# Iterate through a list of integer and lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to iterate through a list that contains a mix of lists and non-list elements. Here's an example:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 8, 9, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I know how to iterate through a mandatory list of lists, but in this case I don't know how to do it. My objective is to compare one value of the nested list with another value in the list. For example in this case: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `8`

Comment: Please give an example of what you want with both input and output.

Comment: @robert i want to compare one value outside the inner list, with the numbers within the inner list, and if they are equal, delete the value in the inner list

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you want.  Please show an example.

Comment: @Andfoy check out my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
thelist = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, [9, 0, 1, 8]]
# Remove the 5 from the first inner list because it was found outside.
# Remove the 8 from the other inner list, because it was found outside.
expected_output =[[1, 2, 3, 4], 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, [9, 0, 1]]
```

Here's a way to do it:

```
thelist = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5, 6, 7, 8, [9, 0, 1, 8]]

expected_output =[[1, 2, 3, 4], 5, 6, 7, 8, [9, 0, 1]]

removal_items = []

for item in thelist:
    if not isinstance(item, list):
        removal_items.append(item)

for item in thelist:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for remove in removal_items:
            if remove in item:
                item.remove(remove)

print thelist

assert thelist == expected_output
```

Comment: So i must separate the lists and the outside values, compare, delete and create again the list?

Comment: @Andfoy, you can use `filter(lambda elem: type(elem) is not list, a)`, which is a built-in function that will remove any `list` element from your main list. As for _create again the list_, you don't have to. The code from @jgritty modifies your original list directly.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different version than the answer from [jgritty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659291/191191). The differences:

- we use the [filter()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) built-in to extract the `int` elements from your list
- we keep the integers in a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead of a `list`
- we iterate over a copy of `a`, so that we can safely remove elements from `a` itself at the same time
- use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to remove members of nested lists that are already in the main list

  ```
  a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5, 6, 7, 8, [9, 0, 1, 8]]
  print a

  numbers = set(filter(lambda elem: type(elem) is not list, a))

  for elem in a:
      if type(elem) is list:
          elem[:] = [number for number in elem if number not in numbers]

  print a
  ```

Comment: Is there a reason you do `for elem in a[:]:` instead of `for elem in a:`?

Comment: Good question. `a[:]` is an idiomatic way of getting a copy of a list in Python.  It is not a good idea to modify a list while iterating over it, as explained in [the online doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)

Comment: It's really only the `elem` list that needs to be copied I think.  It doesn't seem that you're modifying a, only its elements.  Also, I don't iterate over the inner lists for exactly that reason.

Comment: @jgritty good point, there is indeed no need to get a copy of the outer list. I modified my example accordingly. Also, agreed that your version works.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 8, 9, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
for x in a:
    if type(x) is list:
        for y in x:
            print y
    else:
        print x
```

or use

```
isinstance(x, list)
```

Comment: `isinstance` is usually preferable than `type`

Comment: Definitely use `isinstance`, have that as the only way and remove your check of `type`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the object of the iteration is a ListType (http://docs.python.org/library/types.html) and iterate it further.

I cant remember now the exact command but there is something like type(x) that you can use to get the object's type.